# Expected string or buffer with django pipeline when trying to minify js

Tags: python, django, django-pipeline

When I try to this on my base template

```
{% load compressed %}

{% compressed_js 'app_name' %} <- fails here
```

This is my settings.py file:

```
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'app_name': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'static/js/bootstrap.js',
        )
    }
}
```

are this paths right?

I get:

```
Exception Value:    
expected string or buffer
```

any clues?